# Restart Exchange 2010 IIS

Tags: exchange-2010

We recently upgraded to Exchange 2010, but were having some weird login issues(Outlook prompting for passwords). We altered the IIS permissions to hopefully fix this, but need to restart the IIS portion to apply the changes. What kind of downtime came be expected from rebooting IIS, but not the actual machine, which is a VM anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seconds, unless the service fails to respond to the start or stop request, which has a 30 second timeout.  In that event, you're likely looking at a machine reboot as being the fastest solution, which shouldn't take more than a few minutes on a VM (though you could try a `taskkill /f` or `TerminateProcess` if you really want to a avoid a system reboot).